# access vhost from LAN hosted on WAMP win7

Tags: windows-7, lan, wamp

I am able to access localhost by visiting my local ip in the browser from other pcs / phones, tablets, etc but I am not sure how to access the vhosts on that machine.  Is there a syntax for accessing vhosts?

http://192.168.x.x  // gives me localhost

I would like to be able to access something like below

http://192.168.x.x/testsite.local

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the `hosts` file on the other computers on that lan and direct the desired domain name for the vhost to your pc's ip. For linux the hosts file is at `/etc/hosts`, for Windows, `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` mostly.

Suppose, your LAN IP is `192.168.0.11` and you have a vhost setup as `test.yourname.com` and you want to access it from other PCs on that network. Now open the `hosts` file as the admin on other PCs in that LAN, add the following line -

```
192.168.0.11      test.yourname.com
```

and save it. Then restart that PC. Now try to access `http://test.yourname.com` in any browser from those PCs and you should see the vhost that you setup in your PC.

Comment: k, thanks.  And on a related note:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917107/how-can-i-redirect-http-requests-made-from-an-ipad.  I have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer since this is my first post. :)

Comment: Ok. added some more details. Check it out. :)

Comment: thanks again!  this is amazing too - http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/ipad-http-debugging/ , it works for vhosts on the iPad